# Как сравнить дату?

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток? Есть ли способ правильно сравнивать дату? Мне нужно сравнить заданную дату из переменной "Global_variable.date_arrival" с текущей, также после надо сравнить заданное время с текущим.

```
DateArrival.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity(),
dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),

DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
Global_variable.date_arrival = DateArrival.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Берем календарь, заполняем дату/время, дальше сравниваем.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myHours );
            calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, myMinutes );
if( now > calendar.getTimeInMillis() ){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Какой у вас формат времени?

JodaTime вам в помощь. Там отличная математика с DateTime. А вот так это можно сделать через небольшой костыль:

```
Long adjusted = DateTime.parse(adjustedDate).withTime(0,0,0,0).getMillis().get()
Long globalVariable = DateTime.parse(Global_variable.date_arrival).withTime(0,0,0,0).getMillis().get()
if (adjusted != globalVariable) {
    if (adjusted > globalVariable) {
        if (DateTime.parse(adjustedDate).getMillis().get() > DateTime.now().getMillis().get()) {
        } 
    }
}
```

Но стоит порыться в библиотеки, там есть методы для сравнения временных рамок. Сейчас нет вот возможности пошерстить.

Answer (score 0):

В java,util.time есть эти функции. Есть там также встроенные методы (date1).isBefore(date2), isAfter в том же ключе. А также много чего другого.